# Rust multi-threaded cache

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust, and trying to write a cache to hold a bunch of services.
Each service has an associated `String` key, and I want to be able to `get_or_create` and `remove` services from this cache. The tricky part is that I need it to work concurrently: creating the service is a slow operation, and I want threads that try to get the service whilst it is being created to block and wait for it.

Here is the idea I have so far, which I think will work, however it seems quite convoluted. Is there a simpler way, or a library struct I can use instead?

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex, RwLock};

struct MyService { ... }
impl MyService {
  fn new(key: &str) -> Self { ... }
}

struct ServiceCache(RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<(Mutex<Option<Arc<MyService>>>, Condvar)>>>);

impl ServiceCache {
  fn get_or_create(&self, key: &str) -> Arc<MyService> {
    let cache = self.0.read().unwrap();

    match cache.get(key) {
      Some(pair) => Self::get_when_ready(pair.0, pair.1),
      None => {
        let mut cache = self.0.write().unwrap();
        let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(None), Condvar::new()));
        cache.insert(path.to_owned(), Arc::clone(&pair));
        drop(cache);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
          let service = MyService::new(key); // slow process
          let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = &*pair;
          let mut ready = lock.lock().unwrap();
          *ready = Some(Arc::new(service));
          cvar.notify_all();
        });

        Self::get_when_ready(pair.0, pair.1)
      },
    }
  }

  fn remove(&self, key: &str) {
    let mut cache = self.0.write().unwrap();
    cache.remove(key);
  }

  fn get_when_ready(lock: Mutex<Option<Arc<MyService>>>, cvar: Condvar) -> Arc<MyService> {
    let mut ready = lock.lock().unwrap();
    while ready.is_none() {
      ready = cvar.wait(ready).unwrap();
    }

    Ok(ready.unwrap())
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how this cache is used? Do you have any `async` concerns?

Comment: This cache will be accessed from multiple threads that will call `get_or_create`, then use the service (or in some cases call `remove`). Perhaps `get_or_create` should return a `Future` so that I can do `get_or_create(key).await`, however I don't actually mind if the thread just blocks and waits - there is no useful work for the thread to do until the service is available.

Comment: There's `async` compatible [`RwLock`](https://docs.rs/async-rwlock/latest/async_rwlock/) implementations.

Comment: Is adding services rare?

Comment: Yes, adding services can be considered a rare occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the following would work ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f10335669dad7f6ac601682d9bf5ad7)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct MyService {}
impl MyService {
    pub fn new(_key: &str) -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

enum CacheEntry {
    Empty,
    Service(Arc<MyService>)
}

struct ServiceCache(Mutex<HashMap<String, Arc<Mutex<CacheEntry>>>>);

impl ServiceCache {
    fn get_or_create(&self, key: &str) -> Arc<MyService> {
        // First, check if we already have a service in the cache.
        // If we do not, initialize with an empty service before
        // dropping the lock.
        let candidate = {
            let mut cache_lock = self.0.lock().unwrap();
            cache_lock.entry(key.to_string())
                .or_insert_with(|| Arc::new(Mutex::new(CacheEntry::Empty)))
                .clone()
        };

        // From this point, the cache is available for concurrent calls,
        // but we're the sole thread accessing this specific candidate.
        let mut service_lock = candidate.lock().unwrap();
        if let CacheEntry::Service(ref service) = *service_lock {
            // The service was already initialized.
            return (*service).clone();
        }

        // Initialize the service. This will only block clients that
        // expect this specific service.
        let service = Arc::new(MyService::new(&key));
        *service_lock = CacheEntry::Service(service.clone());
        service
    }
}
```

Does this fulfill your needs?

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, the problem with this is that if thread A is busy creating a service with key A, and then thread B wants to access service B (which is already in the cache), then thread B will blocked until thread A has finished creating & inserting its service into the cache.

Comment: I've added a `drop(cache)` to my code which I think should have been there to prevent this problem

Comment: Yes, in my version, thread B will be blocked. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: @MikeJerred Is this a problem for you? This can be solved, but is it really needed?

Comment: > I've added a drop(cache) to my code which I think should have been there to prevent this problem

@MikeJerred, the `drop(cache)` is needed but will not prevent the problem you are describing. But it was my understanding that you did not consider it a problem?

Comment: So, I'm happy for a thread to block trying to get a service if that service is currently being created by a different thread. I am not ok with blocking access to the whole cache when a new service is created - getting services or adding new ones should not be blocked just because a service on a totally different key is being created.

Comment: Alright, that explains why you have both a `RwLock` and ` Mutex`! I'll amend my code to match that requirement.

Comment: Code amended. What do you think of this new version?

Comment: Both `try_lock()`s can fail and you have no protection against that.

Comment: @MikeJerred May I ask: Are you sure this is critical for you? You said adding services is rare. You can easily make it so that adding services will not block getting for the (slow) service creation, only for the (fast) insertion to the map. Do you really care if in this short time window nobody will be able to access the map, and they'll have to wait a little longer?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oops, good catch, I meant to write `lock()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is much simpler than what I wrote originally!

Comment: @MikeJerred Now even reads block reads.

Comment: yeah this code is a bit rough, I have kept a `RwLock` around the `HashMap` for example, but what is really useful is the idea of locking the `HashMap` in order to clone a service `Arc`, then releasing the `HashMap` lock, and doing this in an elegant way using scopes and `.entry().or_insert_with`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good remark. In cases in which this is not ok... well, I guess your solution is better :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this where adding services doesn't block getting other services with the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap) crate, on the assumption that service additions are rare. It does block adding two services at the same time. This is required in order to not add the instantiate the same service twice. The situation can be improved (for example, by holding a map of service keys to mutexes), but if service additions are rare, this should be enough.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct MyService {}
impl MyService {
    pub fn new(_key: &str) -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct ServiceCache {
    data: arc_swap::ArcSwap<HashMap<String, Arc<MyService>>>,
    add_mutex: Mutex<()>,
}

impl ServiceCache {
    fn get_or_create(&self, key: &str) -> Arc<MyService> {
        {
            let cache_handle = self.data.load();
            if let Some(service) = cache_handle.get(key) {
                return Arc::clone(service);
            }
        }

        self.create(key)
    }

    #[cold]
    #[inline(never)]
    fn create(&self, key: &str) -> Arc<MyService> {
        let _guard = self
            .add_mutex
            .lock()
            .unwrap_or_else(|poison| poison.into_inner());
        let mut cache_handle = self.data.load_full();
        if let Some(service) = cache_handle.get(key) {
            // Someone was faster than us and already created the service.
            return Arc::clone(service);
        }
        let data = Arc::make_mut(&mut cache_handle);
        let service = Arc::new(MyService::new(key));
        data.insert(key.to_owned(), Arc::clone(&service));
        // If you allow concurrent adds, this needs to be a compare-and-swap loop.
        self.data.store(cache_handle);
        service
    }
}
```

Note that I've made this on the assumption that service addition are *really* rare, since this allocates a new map every addition. If they are semi-frequent, it is possible to optimize using unsafe code, by storing the `HashMap` in an [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) and appending to it **iff it does not need to grow**.

Comment: Thankyou for this, `arc-swap` and `cold` are instructive